# Terraform: how to read list of maps?

Tags: terraform

See the example below:

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "api_key" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.keys))}"

  secret {
    name    = "secret_name"
    payload = "${element(values(var.keys), count.index)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "access_key" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.keys))}"

  name  = "${var.environment}-${element(keys(var.keys), count.index)}"
  value = "${lookup(element(data.aws_kms_secrets.api_key.*.plaintext, count.index), "secret_name")}"
}
```

It appears to be impossible to look up the plaintext values from the data resource.

`value = "${lookup(element(data.aws_kms_secrets.api_key.*.plaintext, count.index), "secret_name")}"`

Results in `lookup: argument 1 should be type map, got type string in:`

I have tried many combinations of `element`,`lookup`,`*`, and dictionary syntax nothing works.

my `var.keys` looks like:

```
keys = {
  key-name-one = "sssss"
  key-name-two = "sss"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to use the dictionary syntax to replace the element call, it behaves better with lists of maps.

```
value = "${lookup(data.aws_kms_secrets.api_key.*.plaintext[count.index], "secret_name")}"
```

its tempting to do `data.aws_kms_secrets.api_key[count.index].plaintext` that isn't valid HCL

Comment: Your answer will be great with some explanation of how it solves the problem.

Comment: added a bit more explanation

Comment: Yes, using the splat operator as an array instead of element() method solves the problem.

Comment: Problem is, that element() is only capable of working with lists. But what you actually want is a map. That is why the other syntax is used, which is also capable of handling maps. THANK YOU FOR THIS ANSWER! I'd never solved this on my own!

Answer (score 1):

You can also access multiple secrets without using `count` and instead just adding multiple `secret` blocks like this:

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "example" {
  secret {
    # ... potentially other configration ...
    name    = "master_password"
    payload = "AQEC..."
  }

  secret {
    # ... potentially other configration ...
    name    = "master_username"
    payload = "AQEC..."
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  master_password = "${data.aws_kms_secrets.example.plaintext["master_password"]}"
  master_username = "${data.aws_kms_secrets.example.plaintext["master_username"]}"
}
```

This example is given in the [AWS Provider version 2 upgrade guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/version-2-upgrade.html#data-source-aws_kms_secret) as the [`aws_kms_secret` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/kms_secret.html) is incompatible with Terraform 0.12 and so is replaced by the [`aws_kms_secrets`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/kms_secrets.html) (note the pluralisation) data source instead.

I've updated the docs for the `aws_kms_secrets` data source example to match this as well.

In Terraform 0.12 those secrets blocks will also be able to be [dynamic](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each) as well so you should be able to do something like this:

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "example" {
  dynamic "secret" {
    for_each = var.keys

    content {
      name    = secret.name
      payload = secret.payload
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "access_key" {
  count = "${length(var.keys)}"

  name  = "${var.environment}-${element(keys(var.keys), count.index)}"
  value = "${lookup(data.aws_kms_secrets.api_key.plaintext), element(keys(var.keys), count.index)}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't access dictionaries with [] syntax. No way to work with list of dictionaries if it comes from a resource. Here's a workaround:

```
data "external" "extract_domain_validation_options" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/extract_domain_validation_options.py"]

  query {
    encoded = "${jsonencode(flatten(aws_acm_certificate.mycrt.*.domain_validation_options))}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  name    =  "${element(split(",", data.external.extract_domain_validation_options.result.resource_record_name), count.index)}"
  type    =  "${element(split(",", data.external.extract_domain_validation_options.result.resource_record_type), count.index)}"
  records = ["${element(split(",", data.external.extract_domain_validation_options.result.resource_record_value), count.index)}"]
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.myzone.zone_id}"
  ttl     = "60"
  count = "${length(flatten(aws_acm_certificate.mycrt.*.domain_validation_options))}"
}
```

extract_domain_validation_options.py:

```py
import json
import sys

query = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())

result = {}

arr = json.loads(query["encoded"])
for vo in arr:
    for key in vo:
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = vo[key]
        else:
            result[key] += "," + vo[key]

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result))
```