# Terraform list of MySQL usernames and passwords with KMS encrypted passwords

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using Terraform to manage MySQL users in a database. I'd like to pull the usernames, passwords and privileges from variables.

The following works great for the grants, thanks to Terraform 0.12:

```
resource "mysql_grant" "ro" {
  for_each = var.db_grants

  user       = each.key
  host       = "%"
  database   = mysql_database.app.name
  privileges = each.value["privileges"]
  table      = ""
  tls_option = ""
}

variable "db_grants" {
  default = {
    "user1" = {
      "privileges" = ["SELECT"]
    }
  }
}
```

This approach also works great for passwords:

```
resource "mysql_user" "ro" {
  for_each = var.db_passwds

  user               = each.key
  host               = "%"
  plaintext_password = each.value["password"]
  tls_option         = ""
}

variable "db_passwds" {
  default = {
    "user1" = {
      "password" = "password"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like to use data source aws_kms_secrets for the passwords. I have read that it should be possible to use for_each for data sources - https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html but I'm not sure on the syntax for the aws_kms_secrets data source and mysql_user resource to get this working.

I've tried various ways and also tried using a count and lookup with the mysql_user resource but keep drawing a blank! Including this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565099/12473633)

With the following code

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "mysql-ro" {
  dynamic "secret" {
    for_each = var.db_passwords

    content {
      name    = secret.name
      payload = secret.payload
    }
  }
}

variable "db_passwords" {
  default = {
    user1 = "AQICAHiDBkUhG...etc"
    user2 = "AQICAHiDBkJiH...etc"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on data.tf line 37, in data "aws_kms_secrets" "mysql-ro":
  37:       name    = secret.name

This object does not have an attribute named "name".


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on data.tf line 38, in data "aws_kms_secrets" "mysql-ro":
  38:       payload = secret.payload

This object does not have an attribute named "payload".
```

And for the following code:

```
resource "mysql_user" "ro" {
  count              = "${length(var.db_users)}"
  user               = "${lookup(var.db_users[count.index], "username")}"
  host               = "%"
  plaintext_password = "${lookup(data.aws_kms_secrets.mysql-ro.plaintext), element(keys(var.db_passwords), count.index)}"
  tls_option         = ""
}

variable "db_passwords" {
  default = {
    user1 = "AQICAHiDBkUhG...etc"
    user2 = "AQICAHiDBkJiH...etc"
  }
}

variable "db_users" {
  description = "Username and Passwords"

  default = [
    {
      "username" = "user1"
      "password" = "AQICAHiDBkUhG...etc"
    },
    {
      "username" = "user2"
      "password" = "AQICAHiDBkJiH...etc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Extra characters after interpolation expression

  on main.tf line 115, in resource "mysql_user" "ro":
 115:   plaintext_password = "${lookup(data.aws_kms_secrets.mysql-ro.plaintext), element(keys(var.db_passwords), count.index)}"

Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra
characters.
```

Any ideas appreciated. Ultimately, I want to be able to pull KMS encrypted passwords from a variables file.

Comment: I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565099/2291321) a while back before 0.12 was released so was unable to test it but I think that might work for you. If you have any issues with this it might be worth editing your question to include what you tried (with a link to that answer) and then showing the errors so I can fix it up.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - Thanks, I have tried that answer and edited the question to show the errors I get. Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the first option but go with `each.key` and `each.value` instead of `secret.name` and `secret.password` does that work?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR no, that gives the error....Error: Reference to "each" in context without for_each

  on data.tf line 24, in data "aws_kms_secrets" "mysql-ro":
  24:       name    = each.key

The "each" object can be used only in "resource" blocks, and only when the
"for_each" argument is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) with the [`aws_kms_secrets` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/kms_secrets.html) like this:

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "mysql-ro" {
  dynamic "secret" {
    for_each = var.db_passwords

    content {
      name    = secret.key
      payload = secret.value
    }
  }
}

variable "db_passwords" {
  default = {
    user1 = "AQICAH..."
    user2 = "AQICAH..."
  }
}

output "user_passwords_plaintext" {
  value = data.aws_kms_secrets.mysql-ro.plaintext
}
```

If you wanted to feed this into the `mysql_user` resource you'd want to use the [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) on the resource with something like the following:

```
resource "mysql_user" "ro" {
  for_each = data.aws_kms_secrets.mysql-ro.plaintext

  user               = each.key
  host               = "%"
  plaintext_password = each.value
  tls_option         = ""
}
```